# Adding a tab in a GTK-Notebook when using Glade

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I have written a C-program and am studying GTK and Glade to build a GUI and now I am stuck for at least two days:

I need a notebook with one tab. In this tab is a button, if clicked a new tab is added.

I found: 'gtk_notebook_append_page(notebook_pointer, tab_content_pointer, label)' but whatever I do it doesn't work. Especially I am not sure what to take as tab_content. I get one out of three error messages: it complains that it is top level and can't get a parent or it has already a parent or the new tab just can't be inserted.

Does anyone know what to take in glade to be used as tab_content? Or knows an example where I could learn that?

Or do I need to dump glade and write everything in C-code? I found examples for that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have always found it take much less time just to write the code directly instead of fighting with a tool that is supposed to generate the code I want. I have a settings menu that is a similar notebook setup in Gtk+2 (code will be essentially identical in Gtk+3) at [gtk_settings.c](https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkate/blob/master/gtk_settings.c)

Comment: For me it's attractive to separate design of the gui and the functionally in the code.
Maybe I have to write such a task in C-code and then see if I can represent it in this xml-interface. This example is really nothing special there must be a representation in Glade.

Comment: And is there something that I should go for your setup instead of a regular notebook setup?

Comment: No, nothing special about the setup, it's just a systematic building of the notebook through C. The one benefit you do get with writing it in C is you have the fine-tuned adjustments available to you. Such as the `/* table inside frame */` blocks and the fine-tuning of the `gtk_table_set_row_spacings (GTK_TABLE (table), 5);` (and `col`) spacings. I've used glade before (absolutely loved `glade2` that generated the C code that provided a starting point to fine-tune) `glate3` was always more trouble than it was worth as it relies on additional css for fine-tuning.

Comment: It should be mentioned that GtkTable is old an deprecated and GtkGrid should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a notebook with Glade. If you right - click on the tab you want to change,  you can delete its contents. (A tab can contain a single widget, though you can put in a HBox or a Grid to combine several).

Once deleted, you can insert any other widget there. Here is an example:

[image: A window with a notebook]A window with a notebook. First tab contents deleted

[image]Inserted a Box, but by default it's vertical, so...

[image]I changed the property to horizontal

[image]I inserted an image widget in the first space, and a checkbutton in the second. (Change the computer's theme to make is a little more visible.

If you want to add pages from you C-code you can do that too, just get a reference to the notebook, and then modify the tab contents.

As a note, I'd recommend looking at  using Python as manager of your GUI. Managing GUIs in Gtk and C - using Glade or not - is tedious. There are several example on the net about how to do that:

- [Using Python GTK GUI front end with C++ backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314599/using-python-gtk-gui-front-end-with-c-backend)
- [How to use GTK+ 3 in Python to manage your whole application](https://www.bachsau.com/2015/07/13/how-to-use-gtk-3-in-python-to-manage-your-whole-application/)

This code adds a new tab perfectly here:

```
notebook = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "notebook1"));
    if (!notebook) {
        g_critical ("Widget \"%s\" is missing in file %s.",
        TOP_WINDOW, "notebook1");
    }
tab_label = gtk_label_new ("New page's tab");
page_contents = gtk_label_new ("New page's contents");

gtk_notebook_append_page(notebook, page_contents, tab_label);
```

Note that you have to put "notebook1" in the ID field of the notebook's widget in Glade.

Comment: I haven't found it difficult to draw a notebook, however, adding a new page didn't  work. Probably I haven't got a valid reference to the notebook.

The program I wrote is written in C. I need a surface for this program. Therefore, Python doesn't seem to be a good option.